# Only let OpenVPN connected users access FTP server - on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, openvpn, windows-server-2012

Windows server 2008 R2 - I have setup OpenVPN, how do I give users connected to it access to an FTP server on the account (but no other users).

I am using a hardware firewall not Windows Firewall.

Can being on the VPN somehow 'get round' the firewall?

Answer (score 1):

With OpenVPN, your VPN clients would be residing in a separate IP address range. 
You might either set your filters to allow this range for FTP or place your OpenVPN gateway behind the firewall appliance, allowing OpenVPN clients unlimited access. I would not recommend the latter as you would be giving up all control, but I have seen installations doing exactly this for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Our openVPN instance tunnels right through our hardware firewalls without issue. The simple test is to connect the server to a client via openVPN, and block all FTP traffic at the firewall level. Ideally a `If Destination is myServer:FTP and source is any THEN DROP/Reject` type rule. I don't know what format of rules your firewall may take.

If you CAN access FTP from the openVPN client and NOT via the external link, it works.
If you CANNOT access FTP from the openVPN client, you'll have to open FTP to the server from your openVPN ip range and drop/reject it from all others.

---

Obvious alternative depending on the openVPN config and the FTP server software: ONLY listen on the openVPN ip address / adapter

Comment: Thanks - may seem like stupid question - but once VPN is connected, how do I know what address to use to access the FTP server? (the external IP doesn't work, and I can access the FTP server fine from the server itself)